# Groupby Pandas DataFrame and calculate mean and stdev of one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, statistics

I have a Pandas DataFrame as below:

```
   a      b      c      d
0  Apple  3      5      7
1  Banana 4      4      8
2  Cherry 7      1      3
3  Apple  3      4      7
```

I would like to group the rows by column 'a' while replacing values in column 'c' by the mean of values in grouped rows and add another column with std deviation of the values in column 'c' whose mean has been calculated. The values in column 'b' or 'd' are constant for all rows being grouped. So, the desired output would be:

```
   a      b      c      d      e
0  Apple  3      4.5    7      0.707107
1  Banana 4      4      8      0
2  Cherry 7      1      3      0
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You could use a [`groupby-agg` operation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation):

```
In [38]: result = df.groupby(['a'], as_index=False).agg(
                      {'c':['mean','std'],'b':'first', 'd':'first'})
```

and then rename and reorder the columns:

```
In [39]: result.columns = ['a','c','e','b','d']

In [40]: result.reindex(columns=sorted(result.columns))
Out[40]: 
        a  b    c  d         e
0   Apple  3  4.5  7  0.707107
1  Banana  4  4.0  8       NaN
2  Cherry  7  1.0  3       NaN
```

---

Pandas computes the sample std by default. To compute the population std:

```
def pop_std(x):
    return x.std(ddof=0)

result = df.groupby(['a'], as_index=False).agg({'c':['mean',pop_std],'b':'first', 'd':'first'})

result.columns = ['a','c','e','b','d']
result.reindex(columns=sorted(result.columns))
```

yields

```
        a  b    c  d    e
0   Apple  3  4.5  7  0.5
1  Banana  4  4.0  8  0.0
2  Cherry  7  1.0  3  0.0
```

Comment: @unutbu: would you plz check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26601001/calculate-std-manually-using-groupby-pandas-dataframe

Comment: For anybody working through this answer, the 'first' entries for 'b' and 'd' indicate that the first value in the group should be used. For this example, 'b' and 'd' have the same value across all groups, so 'first' is a logical value for these columns.

Answer (score 2):

If values in some columns are constant for all rows being grouped (e.g. 'b', 'd' in the OP), then you can include it into the grouper and reorder the columns later.

```py
new_df = (
    df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'd'])['c'].agg(['mean', 'std'])   # groupby operation
    .set_axis(['c', 'e'], axis=1)                           # rename columns
    .reset_index()                                          # make groupers into columns
    [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]                             # reorder columns
)
```

You can also use named aggregation to have the groupby result have custom column names. The `mean` column is named `'c'` and `std` column is named `'e'` at the end of `groupby.agg`.

```py
new_df = (
    df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'd'])['c'].agg([('c', 'mean'), ('e', 'std')])
    .reset_index()                                          # make groupers into columns
    [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]                             # reorder columns
)
```

[image: res1]

You can also pass arguments to `groupby.agg`. For example, if you need to pass `ddof=0` to `std()` in `groupby.agg`, you can do so using a lambda.

```py
new_df = (
    df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'd'])['c'].agg([('c', 'mean'), ('e', lambda g: g.std(ddof=0))])
    .reset_index()[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']]
)
```

[image: res2]