# Calculate STD manually using Groupby Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas

I was trying to write a solution for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599347/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-calculate-mean-and-stdev-of-one-column-and-add-the) by providing a different and a manual way to calculate a mean and std.

I created the [dataframe as described in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599347/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-calculate-mean-and-stdev-of-one-column-and-add-the)

```
a= ["Apple","Banana","Cherry","Apple"]
b= [3,4,7,3]
c= [5,4,1,4]
d= [7,8,3,7]

import pandas as pd
df =  pd.DataFrame(index=range(4), columns=list("ABCD"))

df["A"]=a
df["B"]=b
df["C"]=c
df["D"]=d
```

Then, I created a list of A's without duplication. Then I went through the items, by grouping everytime the items and calculate the solution.

```
import numpy as np

l= list(set(df.A))

df.groupby('A', as_index=False)
listMean=[0]*len(df.C)
listSTD=[0]*len(df.C)

for x in l:
    s= np.mean(df[df['A']==x].C.values)
    z= [index for index, item in enumerate(df['A'].values) if x==item ]
    for i in z:
        listMean[i]=s

for x in l:
    s=  np.std(df[df['A']==x].C.values)
    z= [index for index, item in enumerate(df['A'].values) if x==item ]
    for i in z:
        listSTD[i]=s

df['C']= listMean
df['E']= listSTD

print df
```

I used `describe()` grouped by "A" to calculate the mean, std.

```
print df.groupby('A').describe()
```

And tested the suggested solution:

```
result = df.groupby(['a'], as_index=False).agg(
                      {'c':['mean','std'],'b':'first', 'd':'first'})
```

I noticed that I got different results when I calculate std ("E"). I am just curious, what did I miss ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are [two kinds of standard deviations (SD)](https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/measures-of-spread-standard-deviation.php): the population SD and the sample SD.

The population SD

[image]

is used when the values represent the entire universe of values that you are studying.

The sample SD

[image]

is used when the values are a mere sample from that universe.

`np.std` calculates the population SD by default, while Pandas' `Series.std` calculates the sample SD by default.

```
In [42]: np.std([4,5])
Out[42]: 0.5

In [43]: np.std([4,5], ddof=0)
Out[43]: 0.5

In [44]: np.std([4,5], ddof=1)
Out[44]: 0.70710678118654757

In [45]: x = pd.Series([4,5])

In [46]: x.std()
Out[46]: 0.70710678118654757

In [47]: x.std(ddof=0)
Out[47]: 0.5
```

`ddof` stands for "degrees of freedom", and controls the number subtracted from `N` in the SD formulas.

The formula images above come from [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Estimation). There the "uncorrected sample standard deviation" is what I (and [others](https://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation-formulas.html)) call the population SD, and the "corrected sample standard deviation" is the sample SD.