# Calculating average/standard deviations of rows containing certain string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large pandas dataframe read as `table`. I would like to calculate the means and standard deviations of the two different groups, `CRPS` and `Age`, so I can plot them in a bar plot with std deviations as the error bars.

I can get the mean calculated by just the `Age` column. **I figured it's a for loop that I have to construct, but I don't know how to construct further than `table["Age"].mean()`, which just gives me the average of all data points' age values. This is where I need some guidance. I want to look in the group column, tell it to calculate the average and standard deviation for the ages of that group. So, an average and standard deviation value for the ages of the `CRPS` group, for example.**

I have the first 25 rows down below just to show what the dataframe looks like. I also have imported `numpy as np` as well.

```
        Group  Age
0       CRPS   50
1       CRPS   59
2       CRPS   22
3       CRPS   48
4       CRPS   53
5       CRPS   48
6       CRPS   29
7       CRPS   44
8       CRPS   28
9       CRPS   42
10      CRPS   35
11  CONTROLS   54
12  CONTROLS   43
13      CRPS   50
14      CRPS   62
15  CONTROLS   64
16  CONTROLS   39
17      CRPS   40
18      CRPS   59
19      CRPS   46
20  CONTROLS   56
21      CRPS   21
22      CRPS   45
23  CONTROLS   41
24      CRPS   46
25  CONTROLS   35
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groupby Pandas DataFrame and calculate mean and stdev of one column and add the std as a new column with reset\_index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26599347/groupby-pandas-dataframe-and-calculate-mean-and-stdev-of-one-column-and-add-the)

Comment: It's a dupe, you need groupby and agg. df.groupby('Group').agg(['mean', 'std'])

Comment: @ia_wing Note that if you are plotting the mean +/- uncertainty you should probably be calculating mean +/- std/sqrt(N), i.e. use the standard error on the mean rather than the standard error straight. Apologies if that is not what you intended.

Comment: Also: Be careful with 'average' which does not necessarily equate to the mean - other averages are median and mode for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need a for-loop.

Instead, you might try something like:

```
table.iloc[table['Group'] == 'CRPS']['Age'].mean()
```

I haven't tested with your table, but I think that will work.

The idea is to first create a boolean array, which is true for row indices where the group field contains `'CRPS'`, then to select all of those rows using `iloc`, and finally to take the mean. You could iterate over all of the groups in the following way:

```
mean_age = dict()
for group in set(table['Group']):
    mean_age[group] = table.iloc[table['Group'] == group]['Age'].mean()
```

Maybe this is where you intended to use a for loop.